# problem with Greek in beamer [Lyx]

Tags: beamer, lyx, amsthm

I am trying to write my thesis presentation in Lyx with Beamer but i have an issue with Greek language ..

when i want to add a definition from drop down menu , the letters dont appear right in the compiled file.

for example if i add Definition , in the compiled pdf appear Δεφινιτιον instead of Ορισμος (Definition in Greek).

I attach a screenshot in order to understand my issue :

[image]

Anny ideas ?

Comment: The issue is related to amsthm automatically loaded by beamer, I added this extra tag to your question.

Comment: Is this maybe `babel`/`polyglossia`-related?

Answer (score 3):

The following works for me: go to `Document` -> `Settings` -> `Language` -> choose `Greek`.

[image]

Output:
[image]